# How to list content of the boot partitions?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

In Windows I can assign a letter to the EFI partition, then `cd` and `dir` in it to view the content.

For example now I see ubuntu, Windows Boot Manager.

But how can I do the same, assuming my boot partition is on `sdb1`?

Answer (score 1):

The EFI partition (yours is sda1) gets mounted at /boot/efi on the standard Ubuntu systems.  You need privs to read that location, but normal tools can list the files there, it's just a FAT filesystem. e.g. `sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/*`